# Array to string conversion Exception Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

Slowly moving a project into Laravel. Using a loop I'm capturing all the form input arrays.

The exception is thrown on:

```
$data[] = "['job_id' => '$jobID', 'first_name' => '$name', 'dob' => '$dob']";
```

Larger context:

```
$jobID = 2;
$data = array();
foreach(Input::get('name') as $row=>$name){

    $name = Input::get('name');
    $dob = Input::get('dob'.$row);

    $data[] = "['job_id' => '$jobID', 'first_name' => '$name', 'dob' => '$dob']";

}

$data_insert = implode(',', $data);

if(!empty($name)) {
    DB::table('job_data')->insert([
        $data_insert
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Probably because `$jobID` isn't defined.

Comment: It is defined in the function. I will drop it in so that does not distract from the actual error. Thanks

Comment: Why is your array a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `$name = Input::get('name');` returns an array. Try removing the line completely, it's unecessary because $name is already defined.